# How to not allow a process to be swapped-out on raspberry pi Zero?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, operating-system, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a robotic arm, whose control signals are dependent on control-loop time. I want to shift the control on Raspberry Pi Zero. It runs an OS which will ideally swap the process out. I don't know when this happens and why it happens. What should be done to not allow the OS to swap-out my Control process ? I searched about it and found that the kernel has to be told not to do so. I have no idea how to do it. If the process is swapped-out, will the time of my control loop remain same ?

Answer (score 1):

Your program can call [`mlockall(MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mlockall) which will prevent any of its pages from being swapped out.  This will probably only work if you are root.

If your real issue is that you need real-time behavior, this is a deeper problem.  There's some information at https://eklitzke.org/mlock-and-mlockall